# Clearing Outlook 2010's mail cache

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

We share a mail account in outlook and when a new folder is created it has issues showing it because it is not in the cache. Does anyone know a way to clear the 2010 cache or force it to reload so these new folders show up?

I do not wish do disable cached mode as our mail is received from a remote location, I would just like to clear it once.

Also, I don't want to recreate my account as I have a lot of settings that are outlook only that will be lost(Favorites etc)

Comment: Not saying this will definitely work, but a good(quick) try would be with [CCleaner](http://filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never Mind, I figured it out.

If you go to *Control Panel* → *Mail* → *Show Profiles*

Then open the profile you want then click on the EMail Accounts and Finally switch to the Data Files Tab you can see the path of the Cache File.

I simply rename this to (old) at the end restarted outlook to find it was preparing for "First Time Use" but when it came back up all my settings were preserved.

I had to terminate some processes called searchprovider or similar to rename this file however.

Comment: +1 Good job at figuring that out. I knew that was there and don't know why I didn't think of that... Most people just rely on others to figure out there problem and you figured it out yourself. Great Job!

Answer (score -1):

Not saying this will definitely work, but a good(quick) try would be with [CCleaner](http://filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/). It can clear a lot of unnecessary temporary data on your computer including office temporary files.

Give it a shot and let me know if it works!

Comment: Tried this already, sadly, it does not clear out the cache.