# Lost use of Spell check feature in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I had a windows live account for my email and somehow I was switched over to Outlook.  This is fine but I have lost the ability to use spell check for any emails I am typing. I have tried every tab I can find but I can not activate the spell check. What do you suggest?
I have Windows 7, using Fire Fox and Hotmail for my email server.

Ed

Comment: Did you try googling? Google had this as the 2nd hit on my query: http://superuser.com/questions/291509/clearing-outlook-2010s-mail-cache

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on Microsoft Answers, Outlook's built in spell checker function does not work with browsers that have their own built-in spell checker. I would recommend you check that Firefox's spell checker function is enabled by:

1) Click on the Firefox button in the top left hand side of the browser and click Options.

2) Go to the Advanced tab.

3) Ensure that you are on the General tab, and then under Browsing, ensure that the 'Check my spelling as I type' function is ticked.

5) Click OK.